# Where does the time get pulled from in the_time()

Tags: date-time, timestamp

I am currently using the following function in my footer

```
<?php the_time( 'Y' ); ?>
```

But the footer keeps showing 2011, instead of 2013.

So where does this time stamp get called from exactly?

Comment: That function is for pulling time data related to posts, if you want the current year you should be looking toward PHPs native [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`the_time()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_time) is for outputting the time at which a post was written, and gets this value from the global `$post`.

I'm guessing you just want php's [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)?

Comment: If you were using any sort of non-english language pack, or that was a possibility, it might be better to just always use date_i18n() instead, to ensure proper translations. For this particular Q it doesn't matter, but it's a good habit to get into.